# ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Model With Optional and Required Properties

Tags: c#, model, required, fortify

When the code has been detected by Fortify Security with the above possible error.

I cannot understand how the models can be manipulated to avoid the possible error.
What sort of checks could be done to avoid the error ?

How do we determine if it is an actual error.

eg :

```
public class TestObject
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TestService { get; set; }
        public int selected { get; set; }

        public TestObject()
        {
        }
}

 [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public ActionResult TestObject DataModel, string command)
        {
        }
```

Since the TestObject has [Required] and not required attributes.Fortify could be raising the error.

Comment: In the world of EAI, it is perfectly fine for properties to be optional.  e.g. the case of searching for customers with an optional Post/Zip code.  Tools like Fortify should not be simply be looking at a model and saying _"that's wrong"_.  Fortify needs to take the whole end-to-end into account.  I think Fortify is exceeding its mandate

Comment: thks. I was finding it frustating as it has simply generated heaps of issues where in reality it is not an issue